# app is undefined in loopback custom js file

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

i am using nodejs loopback framework.i want to run a cron job.i created a custom js file for this cron job in server/boot folder.but when manually i run this file(xyz). app is undefined.my code is below

```
 var app = require('../server.js');
 console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>in test")
 var subscription = app.models.UserNotification;
 console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>..in manage")
 var datasource=subscription.dataSource;
 var query="SELECT DISTINCT userId FROM users_subscription";
  datasource.connector.query(sql,function (err, data) {
  console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>data is>>>>>",data);
  })
```

here is my server.js file

```
   var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
   var loopback = require('loopback');
   var boot = require('loopback-boot');
   var app = module.exports = loopback();
   var passport = require('passport');
   var bodyParser = require('body-parser').urlencoded({
    extended: true
     })
  app.use(bodyParser)
  app.use(loopback.context());
 app.use(loopback.token());
 var path = require("path");
 var url = require('url');
 var http = require('http');
 var fs = require('fs');
 var request = require('request');
 app.start = function() {
// start the web server
return app.listen(function() {
app.emit('started');
var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
  var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
  console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
   });
   };


  app.use(loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client')));
  app.use(loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../admin')));
 app.use(loopback.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../other-dir')));
 boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  if (require.main === module) app.start();
  });
```

Thanks,

Comment: Try replacing the first line with `var app = require("../server.js");`

Comment: @bjskistad..it will work if i will run server.js but i want to run this file individually by nodejs or cron job in this case app is undefiend

Answer (score 2):

It's really impossible to say for sure since you don't include the code that is included with:

```
var app = require('../server');
```

(which would be the most important code to include if the require returns undefined) but if `app` is undefined then it means that the module is loaded but its `module.exports` is undefined.

Do you export anything from that module?

Are you sure that it is really `app` that is undefined and not, say, `app.models`?

Without knowing the code in question those are the most reasonable things to investigate.

### Update

If you don't export anything from your `server.js` (which was my suspection in my answer above, but now you confirmed it with you code and comment) then after this line:

```
var app = require('../server.js');
```

you will not be able to use `app.models.UserNotification`

If you want to use `app.models` in the code that requires `server.js`, then you'll have to add:

```
module.exports.models = SOMETHING;
```

in your `server.js` code. You don't seem to have anything called `models` in `server.js`, you don't export anything as `module.exports.models`, so you can't expect `app.models` to be defined in your code that does:

```
 var app = require('../server.js');
```

Comment: @rsp..hii please check code again .i have include server.js also.i did't eport anything.i want to use this file individually for cron job for updating database everyday